# Is it possible to build an evenly spaced and unconstrained grid in Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Is it possible to build a grid in compose, where the sizes of all elements are even, dictated by the largest content? I'd also like this grid to ***wrap the content*** and not be bound by any pre-set height.

So something like this. Let's assume the grid is full-width and we know there are only 2 columns.

```kotlin
 ____________ ____________
|      1.    |2. Medium   |
|Short stuff |length      |
|            |text        |
|____________|____________|
|3. This is  |            |
|a very long |4. hi!      |
|content here|            |
|____________|____________|
```

I've been trying to create something like this, but I don't think it's possible in Compose, without setting some sort of overall height of the grid?

You could have something like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SampleGrid() {
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(0.5f)) {
            Cell(modifier = Modifier.weight(0.5f))
            Cell(modifier = Modifier.weight(0.5f))
        }
        Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(0.5f)) {
            Cell(modifier = Modifier.weight(0.5f))
            Cell(modifier = Modifier.weight(0.5f))
        }
    }
}
```

So it's a nice 2x2, even grid, but the `weigth` will make the elements grow as high as it wants, until it's constrained by some other view around it or a container with a set height.

We can add on `height(IntrinsicSize.Max)` to the Column modifiers, so then it's kinda *wrap content* but what if the other column has a lot/less of content in it? The heights get out of sync

```kotlin
 ____________ ____________
|      1.    |2. hi!      |
|Short stuff |____________| 
|            |4. hi!      |
|____________|____________|
|3. This is  |
|a very long |
|content here|
|____________|
```

You can build a grid with a `Column` wrapper instead and multiple `Rows`, but you get the same issue.

I've found this is a problem even when using a custom `Layout`, and especially [SubcomposeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/layout/package-summary#SubcomposeLayout(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function2)). We can have one layout depend on another, but what if you calculate the height of one row, and it turns out the second row needs more space because it has more content? Then you'd have to re-measure the first one to make it larger, but it's not allowed to measure twice in Compose.

Is my understanding correct? Is a grid with evenly sized elements, which grows with its largest content (instead of being constrained by some height) **impossible**? Feels to me a bit like a chicken and egg kind of a problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with `.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)` applied to `Row`: it'll limit max height to the smallest `Column` height:

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(200.dp)
        .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
        Cell("Short stuff", modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        Cell(LoremIpsum(10).values.first(), modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
    }
    Column(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
        Cell("Medium length text", modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        Cell("hi", modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! Does it matter here if we use `IntrinsicSize.Min` or `IntrinsicSize.Max`? Trying this out myself, I see no difference in how the grid is laid out. Also, I think I was led astray by the previews - the same grid component wrapped in a `Surface` is taking up all the space on a preview, but it displays fine on a device :(

Comment: Sorry, going a bit mad here - I've tested this again a dozen times and your implementation of the grid covers the whole screen if it's wrapped in a `Surface` set to `fillMaxSize/Height`. However if wrapped around any other container `Box` or `Column` - **also set to `fillMaxSize/Height`** it behaves as expected... that container also being a child of the aforementioned `Surface`... Why?

Comment: @MartynaMaron You're right, there doesn't seem to be a difference between `IntrinsicSize.Min` and `IntrinsicSize.Min` in this case. The second problem seems to be caused by the `Box` parameter `propagateMinConstraints = true`. I'm not sure why `Surface` uses it, but you can apply the right parameters to `Box`, like background and shape.